# Root cause for having a number of zero bytes in regular files

Tags: linux, filesystems, java, corruption

We have corrupt files that contain a number of zero bytes. I wonder what the root cause could be. What I know is:

- All kinds of files that were recently written are affected, they contain a number of zero bytes. For example log files, index files (Apache Lucene indexes), jsp files. So, text files, binary files, all kinds of files.
- The zero bytes always start at a position that is multiple of 4096.
- The number of zero bytes isn't always the same. Example sizes: 2053 bytes, 266 bytes, 243 bytes.
- Some positions of the zero bytes in a file: 0xa000 - 0xa805, 0xc000 - 0xc806, 0xf000 - 0xfc10a, 0x3e000 - 0x3e0f3, 0x3f000 - 0x3f0f3.

A partial hexdump of a log file is:

```
00006fe0  61 6e 64 6c 65 72 20 49  67 6e 6f 72 69 6e 67 20  |andler Ignoring |
00006ff0  63 6f 72 72 75 70 74 20  69 6e 64 65 78 20 5b 2f  |corrupt index [/|
00007000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00007090  2e 20 54 68 69 73 20 69  6e 64 65 78 20 4d 55 53  |. This index MUS|
```

- Looks like just one machine (there are multiple machines with the same configuration doing the same operations, but it looks like it only happens on one machine). But I'm not completely certain.
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.11 (Tikanga) 2.6.18-419.el5
- Applications mainly Java, version:  jdk1.8.0_162
- SAN based mount - 950GB
- 16GB RAM and 6 vCPU
- Server is connected to an external storage array, which is connected through HBA -> FC cables -> SAN Switch -> Storage array

Comment: Looks like the metadata (size of file in inode) is written first, but before the actual data is written to disk something interrupted the system, e.g. hitting the reset button or pulling the FC cable.

Comment: The application doesn't see any I/O errors, and there is no restart... Log files are written to continuously (streamed). It's just that somewhere in the middle you sometimes see zero bytes. When exactly those zero bytes are "introduced" is unclear, but there is no power failure, or error messages that I'm aware of.

Comment: Is this a VM or a physical machine?  Have there been any other symptoms, e.g., unexpected crashes?

Comment: I think it's a physical machine, and there are no other symptoms (except for all kinds of data-related issues, such as checksum mismatch).